# How to check if location.hash has `#access_token=` and if so, do something?

Tags: javascript

Right now, I'm just doing the following for my Auth0 login -

```
if (location.hash) {
  // do something
}
```

How can I make sure it will only do this when it includes `#access_token=` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `indexOf` like so.

```
if(location.hash.indexOf("#access_token=" > -1) {
       // Do stuff
}
```

You can learn more on `indexOf` [here](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/string/indexof).